# If (someone) were to become vs. if (someone) became... + COULD

Tags: grammar, modal-verbs

Let's say there is a married couple, Sandra and Jake. Sandra wanted to go to her ailing mother, whereas, Jake wanted to go on a holiday next week. If they didn't go to her mother:

> if Sandra's mother **were to become** seriously ill, Sandra **could** not forgive here husband.

To

> if Sandra's mother **became** seriously ill, Sandra **could** not forgive here husband.

This is a 2nd conditional modal verbs usage, and I know how to construct #2 sentence. But why is that **were to become** was used instead of the other?

If an ESL would like **to use both of them**, are they **grammatical** to use?

P.S.: There is a correct answer below, but, I have just edited this to clarify what I am really trying to ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both sentences are grammatically correct. The second sentence uses a [backshift](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/sentence/reported-speech-backshift.htm) to indicate that we are talking about a hypothetical situation- this is used for all verbs except **be**. The first one uses a proper subjunctive **were** (the only one!).

The first (with **were**) is, in my opinion, stronger in suggesting a hypothetical situation. In this situation-  Sandra's mother is probably no spring chicken and already 'ailing'- we are probably talking about something that could really happen, so the less strongly hypothetical version **became** is more appropriate.

The **were** version is slightly more formal than the **became** version, but both are a lot more formal, and less widely used, than one using **got** if you make the second part less formal too, you get:

> If Sandra's mother [got] seriously ill, Sandra [would never] forgive here husband.

This [NGram graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=if%20I%20got%20ill%2Cif%20I%20became%20ill&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cif%20I%20got%20ill%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cif%20I%20became%20ill%3B%2Cc0) shows the trend toward the less formal (**got**) usage: remember that Google Ngrams is based mainly on written English, and for informal usage it lags a long way behind spoken English.

Answer (score 3):

The `if -- were` form is called the [subjunctive mood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_subjunctive) or just *subjunctive*. It is used in a hypothetical situation, contrary to fact.

An example would be the [lyrics](http://www.metrolyrics.com/if-i-were-a-rich-man-lyrics-jerry-bock.html) for [*If I Were a Rich Man*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/If_I_Were_a_Rich_Man_(song)), by Harnick and Bock.

> If I were a wealthy man...
>
> If I were rich, I'd have the time that I lack...

Poor Tevye doesn't have two kopeks to rub together in his pocket, so being rich is contrary to fact.

Comment: No... this is not the answer I need, but thx anyway.

Comment: But it is correct.  Why do you not need a correct answer?

Comment: @JamesK, True, the information provided here is correct, but it doesn't actually answer the question.

Comment: It is accurate, not correct ;)

Answer (score 1):

The two sentences are constructed differently, but they are both valid expressions of conditional II. See the [Wikipedia summary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_conditional_sentences#Second_conditional):

> If the condition clause uses the past tense of another verb, it may be replaced by the auxiliary construction *were to* + infinitive (particularly if it has hypothetical future reference).

There's no functional difference between the two, except that "were to" sounds more formal to most speakers; in casual conversation, you would be more likely to use sentence #2.